# heat kernel on n-sphere

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, smooth-manifolds, parabolic-pde, laplacian, heat-equation

I'm interested in diffusion, a.k.a. the heat kernel driven by the Laplace-Beltrami operator, on the $n$-dimensional sphere.  There are lots of bounds showing that, for small times, it behaves in a way close to the heat kernel in $\mathbb{R}^n$: that is, the probability $p_t(\theta)$ that we have moved an angle $\theta$ away from the starting point, at time $t$, is bounded by a Gaussian of variance $t$.  But I need some control on how the errors or leading constants in these bounds depend on $n$.

The most precise estimates I've found (where the sphere has radius $1$) is due to Molchanov, 
$$
p_t(\theta) \sim \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\theta^2/2t}}{(2\pi t)^{n/2}} \left( \frac{\theta}{\sin \theta} \right)^{(n-1)/2}
$$
This is the first term of an asymptotic series, and if I understand his paper correctly, for fixed $n$ the next term would give a multiplicative error of $1+O(t)$.  But does the constant hidden in $O(t)$ grow rapidly with $n$?

Another family of bounds gives
$$
p_t(\theta) \le C \,t^{-n/2} \,\mathrm{e}^{-\theta^2/(4+\delta)t}
$$
Any constant value of $\delta$ would be fine with me.  But we need $C$ to decay roughly as $(4\pi)^{-n/2}$ to match the normalization of the flat-space Gaussian.

All we really need for our application is the following.  If we think of the heat kernel as a stochastic process, let $\theta$ be the angular distance from the initial point.  We know that for small enough $t$ we have 
$$
\mathbb{E}(\theta) \le C' \sqrt{nt}
$$
for some constant $C'$, as it would be in flat space; but we need to know this holds for all $t$ up to $1/n$ or so.  In other words, we need to know that the error term doesn't do something horrible like
$$
\mathbb{E}(\theta) = C' \sqrt{nt} + O(2^n t) \, . 
$$
This would follow, for instance, from a bound on the error term in Molchanov's estimate above, although this might be overkill.

Thanks!

Cris

Comment: What's a reference or link to the Molchanov paper?

Comment: Diffusion Processes and Riemannian Geometry, Russian Math. Surveys 30:1 (1975), 1-63.

Comment: Good news: I can show that for diffusion on $S_n$ after time t, the angle $\theta$ away from the starting point has second moment $\mathbb{E}[\theta^2] \le 2nt$, i.e., it's bounded below what it would be in flat space.  It turns out this is easy: we just use the Laplacian to compute the time derivative of $\mathbb{E}[\theta^2]$, and integrate by parts.  In particular, this shows that $\mathbb{E}[\theta] \le \sqrt{2nt}$.  Note that this applies for all $t$, not just for short times.

Comment: Of course, the second moment is special.  A similar integration doesn't work for other (higher) moments.  So I'm still curious whether $\theta$ on $S_n$ is stochastically dominated by $\theta$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: the asymptotic expansion doesn't work in high dimension c.f. https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fams.2018.00001/full

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is true that $\theta$ on $S_n$ is dominated by $\theta$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $(B_t)$ be a Brownian motion on the sphere. The radial process $\theta_t=d(x,B_t)$ is a Jacobi process, that is a Markov process with generator

$
L=\frac{n-1}{2} \text{cotan} (r) \frac{d}{dr} +\frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2}{dr^2 }
$

Since $ \text{cotan} (r) \le \frac{1}{r}$, we deduce from the comparison theorem for stochastic differential equations that

$
\theta_t \le \beta_t
$

where $\beta_t$ is a Bessel process, that is a Markov process with generator

$
L=\frac{n-1}{2r} \frac{d}{dr} +\frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2}{dr^2 }
$

The Bessel process is the radial part of the Euclidean Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so you get the desired stochastic domination.